# One SSL certificate on 2 sites, with same domain but different ports

Tags: ssl, iis

So I have two sites running under the same domain, let's say domain is example.com. Now under the IIS I have two website which can be accessed as example.com and example.com:8080. I want to use the same SSL certificate for both so both can be accessed through HTTPS but I'm not managing. So right now example.com is currently configured to SSL using rewrite module so it automatically redirects to SSL, and this is running finr. I tried to do the same thing on the 2nd website but in bindings for SSL I opted for another port in this case 8081. However when I am trying to access the other website on https://example.com:8081 after proper binding in IIS it is redirecting to https://example.com which is the other website.

Can someone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have rewrite rule applied for 2nd website running on port 8080? If yes please check your rewrite rule to ensure that port 8081 is included in the https redirect

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. I actual did not have but now that I did it, when adding the rewrite it is also adding the protocol together with the existing one. Thus example.com:8080 is being turned to example.com:8080:8081. when I tried to write directly example:8081 it goes to the other website which is correctly being set and thus example.com.